# php: redirect()?

Tags: php, redirect

This is not a request for a solution, but just to clarify something.

When I do a redirect in php I use header()

but while going through someone else's class code I came across this:

```
 // Redirect to target
 redirect(proxifyURL($url, 'norefer'));
```

What the heck is that? And php does not seem to be throwing an error.

I tried looking it up by going to php.net/redirect
but it shows me the header function that I usually use, not this redirect() !!??

Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: have you looked through the whole source code? that looks like an own function.

Comment: use your ide to search for "redirect" occurences in that project folder

Comment: Yep, found it in one of the included files, thanks guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably a user-defined function. This means that the function isn't present in standard PHP, but that the author of the code you read made it himself.

Comment: Ah yes, I found it in one of the included files!   
Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 4):

He probably defined a new function that looks something like this

```
function redirect($to)
{
    header("Location: $to");
    die();
}
```

Comment: you can't know if that function uses header or maybe just put a meta tag redirect in the html

Comment: it doesn't matteR! I'm just showing example how can be redirect() function declared ...

Comment: i guess he know how a function is declared

Comment: @genesis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1552/discussion-between-yes123-and-genesis)

Comment: @genesis: Say so then (i.e. "He probably defined a new function that looks something like this", not "He did X" as if you knew exactly how the function was defined)

Comment: do you think therE's any more possibilities to "declare" function ?